# Xamarin Forms iOS View touch points not getting properly when accessibility voice over enabled in iPhone

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, accessibility

#### Description

Xamarin Forms iOS View touch points not getting properly when accessibility voice over enabled in iPhone

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Touch the view before enabling the accessibility in iPhone.
2. Then touch the view after enabling the accessibility in iPhone.
3. Check the difference of the points.

#### Expected Behavior

Need to get the same touch points before enabled the accessibility to drag the view based on the points.

#### Actual Behavior

Not getting exact touch points after enabled the accessibility. Example: when accessibility disabled and touch the view at particular point getting the points (X,Y) as 7,13 but enabled the accessibility and touch the view at same point getting the points (X,Y) as 50,150.

#### Basic Information

VS 2019
Tested device: iPhone
XF version: 4.8

### Code

[XAML]

```
    <local:MyImageView Margin="0,50,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center"
   HorizontalOptions="Center"
   BackgroundColor="Blue" 
   WidthRequest="300"
   HeightRequest="100">
    </local:MyImageView>
```

[C#]

```
    public class MyImageView : Image
    {

    }
```

CustomRenderer:

```
...
        public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);

            // Getting different touch points when enable and disable the accessiibility voice over.
            CGPoint touchPoint = ((UITouch)touches.AnyObject).LocationInView(this);
        }
...
```

### Sample Link:

[ViewTouchSample.zip](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/files/6118826/ViewTouchSample.zip)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin iOS UIVIew not dragging due to the touch points not getting properly when accessibility voice over enabled in iPhone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66582818/xamarin-ios-uiview-not-dragging-due-to-the-touch-points-not-getting-properly-whe)